# time interval in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to execute the following function every 5 seconds. I am working in backbone and javascript and I don't have any idea how to accomplish this.

The code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        crossDomain: true
    });
    var a = new ServerCollection();
    var collectionView = new ServerCollectionView({collection:a});
    collectionView.collection.fetchData();
    $("#content").append(collectionView.$el);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple working example http://jsfiddle.net/dLsXj/

And here is a working version for your Backbone code:

```
function myFunction() {
    // Be sure to `return collection.fetch();` in `fetchData()` method 
    // to wait while collection will be updated
    collectionView.collection.fetchData().done(function() {
        // Run the function next time after 5 sec when collection will be populated
        setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
    });
}

// We can setup ajax and collection/view without document ready
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    crossDomain: true
});
var a = new ServerCollection();
var collectionView = new ServerCollectionView({collection:a});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // We need to wait document ready to append element
    $("#content").append(collectionView.$el);

    // Run the function first time without timeout
    myFunction();
});
```

I used `setTimeout` only because we are working with async load. For example if we use `setInterval` with 5 sec and collection will be loaded after 7 sec it won't be fair.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
var inter = setInterval(function() { ...}, 5000);

....

clearInterval(inter);
```